# Accessing Customer Default Shipping Address in Netsuite via SuiteTalk Webservices

Tags: c#, web-services, netsuite

I had a lot of trouble finding this so I wanted to share (posting my own answer), particularly because there seems to be very few NetSuite code examples out there.

the default address in NetSuite is NOT the same as the checkbox field that specifies if an address is the default one. The checkbox field is denoted as `defaultShippingSpecified`, but I need to figure out how to access that field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is my method to find all of a customers addresses, and mark the one specified as default. This runs alongside a function to take sales order lines and populate the lines with 'ship to' information.

```
        private Dictionary<string, string> getCustomerAddressID(String customerInternalID)
    {
        RecordRef customerRef = new RecordRef
        {
            internalId = customerInternalID,
            type = RecordType.customer,
            typeSpecified = true
        };

        Dictionary<string, string> listOfAddresses = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        ReadResponse readResponse = _service.get(customerRef);
        if (readResponse.status.isSuccess)
        {
            //type cast to get "instance" of record
            Customer customer = (Customer)readResponse.record;

            //var addressBookList = customer.addressbookList;
            var defaultShippingInternalID = "";
            var addrBook = customer.addressbookList.addressbook;

            foreach (CustomerAddressbook addr in addrBook)
            {
                if (addrBook.Length == 1 || addr.defaultShippingSpecified)
                {
                    defaultShippingInternalID = addr.internalId;
                    listOfAddresses.Add("default", defaultShippingInternalID);
                }
                else { listOfAddresses.Add("alternate", addr.internalId); }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Get customer Failed");
            displayError(readResponse.status.statusDetail);
        }
        return listOfAddresses;
    }
```

Comment: Just to avoid doubt, your use of Dictionary implies you can only have one alternative address (Dictionary.Add would otherwise fail) but it's possible to have more than one. Also, it's possible to have multiple addresses with none of them specified as a default shipping address.

Comment: By the way, defaultShippingSpecified only means that the default shipping field is specified.  It may be specified as false. So you need to check (defaultShippingSpecified && defaultShipping).

Comment: Ah - both good points. This is still in development and was only being used as a proof of concept for part of a larger process, but you're right...the dictionary should be something a list, or some other collection. I also did not think about the default shippingSpecified being specified as false...